# Is there a way to ask permission to a browser, with restricted cookies policy, to accept the cookies of my app?

Tags: browser, permissions, session-cookies, setcookie

I implemented a session with a secure cookie from the server. But on my employer's PC it's not stored.

I maganed to reproduce this behavior denying cookies on my browser. Is there a way, API, to ask permissions for my app to store cookies?

even better if you could provide a way to use it on nextjs, but with the javascript API could do.

I am not talking about GDPR cookie consent.

I have read documentation to ask permissions through manifest.json, I thought service workers could have access to the browser API, but i haven't been able to implement a succesfull test, not even one that can throw light